# I can't access VM IIS hosting application in locally

Tags: .net-core, iis, hosting

I have hosted my dotnet application in my VM's IIS with domain name , in VM i can able to access the application using ip and domain name both, externally i can able to access only using ip address  i can't able to the application using domain name

How can i access the iis hosting application with domain name externally

Comment: Learn about DNS and use `nslookup` command to study how you configured DNS. When in doubt, ask your network administrators for assistance.

Answer (score 0):

If you host the dotnet application in the IIS of the virtual machine and configure the host file in the etc folder (path: %windir%\system32\drivers\etc), you can only use the domain name to access it in the virtual machine . Because the local etc/hosts file of the virtual machine is only used to provide domain name resolution services to the local system. The system you are trying to access the website from outside is not aware of this mapping and cannot resolve the domain name to an IP.

You can use the following methods:

1. If you have a DNS server available in your network, you can register the name there. (recommend)
2. You can add a mapping in the hosts file of each system that you want to access the website.